# How to fetch more than 250 products from Shopify's API in python

Tags: python, pagination, shopify, shopify-api

I am trying to get all the products from a Shopify store using Shopify's python API but I can only get 250 results.

I tried to use pagination and this is the code:

```
def get_all_resources(resource):
    page_info = str()
    resources = list()
    while True:
        resources.extend(resource.find(limit = 250, page_info=page_info))
        cursor = shopify.ShopifyResource.connection.response.headers.get('Link')
        if 'next' in cursor:
            page_info = cursor.split(';')[-2].strip('<>').split('page_info=')[1]
        else:
            break
        return resources

products = get_all_resources(shopify.Product)
```

Unfortunately this still doesn't work and when I print products there are only 250

Comment: [breath in.... breath out.... breath in..... and out]. Hello welcome to Stackoverflow. Did you notice that you are passing a parameter `limit = 250` to the `resource.find` function? Have you maybe tried changing this parameter value and see what happens? Do you thing maybe this parameter has something to do with only getting 250 results?

Comment: Don't know if that's the problem but `return resources` is mis aligned. @SembeiNorimaki 250 is the limit of the api i think.

Comment: But if it's the limit of the API, then the OP would have tried for example to pass `limit = 500` and then either get an error, or get only 250 results, and then asking: I'm only receiving 250 results **although** I'm requesting 500. As the code is now, 250 results are being returned because 250 results are being requested. It's like putting a speed limiter to your car and asking why it doesn't run faster than that. Put the speed limit to 100Km/h and if the car doesn't exceed 50Km/h then we talk, but if it gets to 100Km/h then it's normal behavior

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki he's just trying to read all the results that are paginated.

Comment: oh, then he just have to move the return out of the loop